# Creating a tree node diagram

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am trying to create a tree like node diagram, like the [example image here](http://i39.tinypic.com/rclyc1.jpg). I have the following code:

```
    private void DrawNode(Graphics g, Node<T> node, float xOffset, float yOffset)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap bmp = (from b in _nodeBitmaps where b.Node.Value.Equals(node.Value) select b.Bitmap).FirstOrDefault();

        if (bmp != null)
        {
            g.DrawImage(bmp, xOffset, yOffset);

            DrawNode(g, node.LeftNode, xOffset - 30 , yOffset + 20);
            DrawNode(g, node.RightNode, xOffset + 30, yOffset + 20);
        }
    }
```

My code is almost working. The problem I'm having is that some of the nodes are overlapping. In the picture above, nodes 25 and 66 are overlapping. The reason, I'm sure, is because its mathematically laying the left nodes and right nodes equal space, so the parent's right node overlaps with the adjacent parent's left node. How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE:

This is the code update I made after dtb's suggestion:

```
            int nodeWidth = 0;
            int rightChildWidth = 0;

            if (node.IsLeafNode)
            {
                nodeWidth = bmp.Width + 50;
            }
            else
            {
                int leftChildWidth = 0;

                Bitmap bmpLeft = null;
                Bitmap bmpRight = null;

                if (node.LeftNode != null)
                {
                    bmpLeft =
                        (from b in _nodeBitmaps where b.Node.Value.Equals(node.LeftNode.Value) select b.Bitmap).
                            FirstOrDefault();
                    if (bmpLeft != null)
                        leftChildWidth = bmpLeft.Width;
                }
                if (node.RightNode != null)
                {
                    bmpRight =
                        (from b in _nodeBitmaps where b.Node.Value.Equals(node.RightNode.Value) select b.Bitmap).
                            FirstOrDefault();
                    if (bmpRight != null)
                        rightChildWidth = bmpRight.Width;
                }

                nodeWidth = leftChildWidth + 50 + rightChildWidth;
            }


            g.DrawImage(bmp, xOffset + (nodeWidth - bmp.Width) / 2, yOffset);

            if (node.LeftNode != null)
            {
                DrawNode(g, node.LeftNode, xOffset, yOffset + 20);
            }
            if (node.RightNode != null)
            {
                DrawNode(g, node.RightNode, xOffset + nodeWidth - rightChildWidth, yOffset + 20);
            }
```

Here is a screenshot from this code: [image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Not sure how we would know how to fix the problem, since you can handle it any way you want: Shrink the nodes! Shift the parents! Allow the overlap! Just decide on a strategy, calculate when that strategy will be needed, and implement it.

Comment: @dlev -- its not that easy. If I shift the parents, the same problem happens to the children (who are also parents) below it. Shrinking the nodes also doesn't help...that just shrinks them, but still overlaps them. Its got to be some kind of mathematical solution

Comment: I don't mean to be flip: I glossed over the "calculate when that strategy will be needed", but that is indeed the crux of this issue. Tough to say more without knowing exactly how you want to lay everything out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign a width to each `node`:

- the width of a leaf is the width of the image, `w`.
- the width of a node is the width of its left child node + a constant `d` + the width of the right child node.

[image: Illustration]

```
void CalculateWidth(Node<T> node)
{
    node.Width = 20;
    if (node.Left != null)
    {
        CalculateWidth(node.Left);
        node.Width += node.Left.Width;
    }
    if (node.Right != null)
    {
        CalculateWidth(node.Right);
        node.Width += node.Right.Width;
    }
    if (node.Width < bmp.Width)
    {
        node.Width = bmp.Width;
    }
}
```

Starting with the root node and `x = 0`, draw the image at the halve of the width, offset by `x`.
Then calculate the `x` position for each child node and recurse:

```
void DrawNode(Graphics g, Node<T> node, double x, double y)
{
    g.DrawImage(x + (node.Width - bmp.Width) / 2, y, bmp);

    if (node.Left != null)
    {
        DrawNode(g, node.Left, x, y + 20);
    }
    if (node.Right != null)
    {
        DrawNode(g, node.Right, x + node.Width - node.Right.Width, y + 20);
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
CalculateWidth(root);

DrawNode(g, root, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working right. For example, when rendered to the screen, Node 5 is right under Node 20, just to the left. That's fine. But Node 25 is pushed off to the right. Nodes 75 and 95 are also overlapping. I can post the code if that'll help.

Comment: Okay, I just updated my question. I included the changes I made to the code and a screen shot.

Comment: You are aware that, before you can calculate the width of 50, you first need to calculate the width of 20 and 75, right?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. Look at the `leftChildWidth` and `rightChildWidth` calculations in the code I posted

Comment: But you always set `leftChildWidth` to `bmpLeft.Width`. The width of 20 is not `w` but `width(5) + d + width(25)`.

Comment: Oh I got you. And the width of 20 should be the width of width(5) + d + width(25) and if 5 and 25 have children, I need to keep traversing down the chain till I get to the leaf nodes, right?

Comment: Ugh its giving me really weird results. Is it possible I could email you my solution and project and you could take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that they're going to overlap. It's because you're adding/subtracting a fixed value to xOffset as you traverse down the tree. In the example picture, it's not actually a fixed offset: rather, it's <s>logarithmic</s> exponential with respect to its vertical position. The further down you go, the smaller the offset should be.

<s>Replace the 30s with `A * Math.Log(yOffset)`, where A is some scaling value that you'll have to tweak until it looks right.</s>

**EDIT**: or is it exponential? I can't visualize this stuff too well. You might end up wanting `A * Math.Exp(-B * yOffset)` instead. (The negative is significant: this means it'll get *smaller* with larger yOffset, which is what you want.)

`A` will be like your master, linear scaling factor, while `B` will control how quickly the offset gets smaller.

```
double A = some_number;
double B = some_other_number;
int offset = (int)(A * Math.Exp(-B * yOffset));
DrawNode(g, node.LeftNode, xOffset - offset , yOffset + 20);
DrawNode(g, node.RightNode, xOffset + offset, yOffset + 20);
```

**Update:**

```
double A = 75f;
double B = 0.05f;
int offset = (int)(A * Math.Exp(-B * (yOffset - 10)));
DrawNode(g, node.LeftNode, xOffset - offset, yOffset + 20);
DrawNode(g, node.RightNode, xOffset + offset, yOffset + 20);
```

Called with:

```
DrawNode(e.Graphics, head, this.ClientSize.Width / 2, 10f);
```

The `- 10` in the Exp is significant: it is the initial yOffset of the head. It produces the following:

[image]

If you want precise margin/padding control then by all means go with dtb's method, but I think 3 extra lines with a single formula is as elegant a mathematical solution as you're going to get.

**Update 2:**

One more thing I forgot: I'm using base `e = 2.7183`, but you'd want something closer to 2. Logically you would use exactly 2, but because the nodes have non-zero widths you might want something a bit bigger, like 2.1. You can change the base by multiplying `B` by `Math.Log(new_base)`:

```
double B = 0.05f * Math.Log(2.1);
```

I should also explain how I got the value of 0.05f. Basically, you're increasing `yOffset` by 20 for each level of the tree. If I subtract the initial `yOffset` of the head (which is 10 in my case), then my first few `yOffset`s are 0, 20, 40, 60, etc. I want the x offset to be cut in half for each row; that is,

```
2 ^ (-0B) = 1
2 ^ (-20B) = 0.5
2 ^ (-40B) = 0.25
```

Obviously, B needs to be 1/20, or 0.05. I get the `Math.Log(2.1)` value from the relation:

```
base ^ exponent == e ^ (ln(base) * exponent)
```

So, with base 2.1, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Won't it need to be Log base 2, not 10?

Comment: I saw it wrong in my head, it's actually exponential (with a negative exponent). Log10 and Log2 are asymptotically the same -- that is, Log10 x = C * Log2 x, for some constant C.

Comment: You are right, it's a negative exponent.  As for the log base, It's true that there is a constant difference, but that constant will be log base 10 of 2 (in your example).  Since there will be at least one additional constant for scaling (the width of the total space) it's clearer in my mind to separate out each constant rather than rolling them up all into one big 'C' without defining it.

Comment: Jeff, this solution doesn't seem to work, as it seems to spread out the to row fine, but then all the rows below it line up exactly under each other.

Comment: I forget to mention that precise care needs to be taken in calculating B. I tried implementing it when I got home and I get something like this, the answer is updated: http://i.imgur.com/hfedP.png